# Difference in digits of precision in float and double

Tags: c, floating-point

```
main()
{
    int z;
    float b=3.1;
    z=b*5+1.5;
    printf("%d",z);
}
```

I get value of z as 16.

When I use double I get 17. Why so?

Comment: Try `printf("%.20f",b*5+1.5);` to see the difference yourself.

Comment: Floating-point is inherently imprecise, so the floating-point value might've been just below 17, and `int`s are truncated/rounded down when cast. These are both frequently asked questions about C. Also, `main()` returns `int`. Also, there is no `double` here, except the literals along the way,

Comment: You're using `%d` format specifier, which means you're not printing float or double

Comment: What compiler are you using? With gcc5.4 is printing 17 for both.

Comment: Both `double` and `float` can only exactly encode a finite about amount of numbers.    About 2^32 different numbers for `float` and 2^64 for `double`.  Neither can store 3.1 exactly yet use a close approximation.  Since they use a difference approximation, subsequent code gives you 2 different results.

Comment: Prawin What was you output with `double/float` and `printf("%.20f",b*5+1.5);`?

Comment: @chux 3.10000000000000008882 for double
 3.09999990463256835938 for float

Comment: @chux 3.10000000000000008882 for double
 3.09999990463256835938 for float

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many numbers like 3.1 that `float/double` cannot encode *exactly* given that floating point typical uses a *binary* floating point encoding.  **1 In OP's case, rather than saving exactly 3.1 in `b`, a nearby value is saved.   As a `float` and `double`, different approximations were used leading to the 16 vs. 17.

The result of the FP math and the  `int` truncation accentuates this difference.

```
#include <float.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("%d\n",FLT_EVAL_METHOD);
    float b=3.1;
    printf("%.20f %.20f %d\n",b, b*5+1.5, (int) (b*5+1.5));
    volatile float v=3.1;
    printf("%.20f %.20f %d\n",v, v*5+1.5, (int) (v*5+1.5));
    double d=3.1;
    printf("%.20f %.20f %d\n",d, d*5+1.5, (int) (d*5+1.5));
}
```

Output

```
2
3.09999990463256835938 16.99999952316284179688 16
3.09999990463256835938 16.99999952316284179688 16
3.10000000000000008882 17.00000000000000000000 17
```

---

Sometimes the effects of `FLT_EVAL_METHOD`, which allow for some `float` math to be done as `double` math complicates the story.  So the above uses a `volatile float` to help should others try variations on this code.

---

Tip: With ample warnings, code may get a warning like the following.  This hints that `3.1` and `3.1f` are not the same.

```
// warning: conversion to 'float' alters 'double' constant value [-Wfloat-conversion]
float b=3.1;  

// no warning
float b=3.1f;
```

---

As an alternative to assigning a FP value to an `int` directly, consider the various rounding functions like `round(), roundf(), nearby(), rint(), lrint()`, etc.

```
#include <math.h>
// example: float to long
long int lrintf(float x);
long long_var = lrintf(float_var);
```

---

**1 There are infinite number of numbers. Yet only about 2<sup>32</sup> different `float`.

Answer (score 1):

3.1 cannot be represented precisely as a binary floating point number, just like 3⅓ cannot be represented precisely in decimal. So what will be stored in `b` is the closest possible value as a `float` (or `double`) if you change the type of `b`. That might be slightly less or slightly more, depending on where the fraction needs to be truncated.

If it turns out to be slightly more, `5*b+1.5` will be slightly more. than 17; otherwise it will be slightly less. But converting to an `int` throws away the fraction, so this tiny difference suddenly becomrs important.

You should avoid the instability by [rounding](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/round) rather than truncating.